# python pandas findall: dashed words and words

Tags: python, regex

Below is an example:

```
se1 = pd.Series(['x whitet-shirtlarge 100% high-quality menshirt'])
se1.str.findall('t-shirt|[a-z]+').str.join(' ')
```

The output is:

```
x whitet shirtlarge high quality menshirt
```

My expected output is (note the dashed word t-shirt):

```
x whitet-shirtlarge high quality menshirt
```

How to achieve my expected output?
Thank you.

Additional note:
The below expression will yield result very close to my expectation:

```
se1.str.findall('t-shirt|[a-z\s]').str.join('')
```

output:

```
x whitet-shirtlarge  highquality menshirt
```

The issue is that 'high' 'quality' are connected into one word

Comment: are you trying to replace all `-` (dash) with ` ` (space) _except_ the `-` in the word `t-shirt`?

Comment: @HaleemurAli very close. I want to keep only letters ([a-z]) and defined dashed word ('t-shirt' in this example). My expression seems working when testing in regexr.com, but failed in python.

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the right answer. The regex you are looking for is `'t-shirt|[a-z-]+'`. A dash `'-'` in a range `'[...]'` is treated as a special symbol, unless it is the first or the last character in the brackets.

Comment: `t-shirt|[a-z-]+` will yield `x whitet-shirtlarge high-quality menshirt`, and note that the dash in `high-quality` is not wanted.